# Showing border on UITableView properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, border

I am trying to polish up my tableview by showing a border on it.
This is how it currently looks like:

[image]

Everything is fine expect the bottom part. I want the border to be on the bottom of the last showing cell's separator.

This is how it looks like when without the border:

[image]

I am using a footer like this and add the border like this:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


tableView.layer.masksToBounds = true
tableView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

**NOTE**

Another thing i forgot to mention to think about. I thought of putting the height of the border according to how many cells there are. Yes i will always have the same amount of cells however on different screens, not all cells will be showing.

Comment: Do you need the border to be static or do you want it to move with the last cell?

Comment: you have to adjust your tableview's frame to match it's contentsize...

Comment: Off topic but I just wanted to say that your project idea is ingenious. Keep going!

Comment: It should move with the last cell (SHOWING ON SCREEN). Cause the screenshot i provided is able to  show all 8 rows. However on an iphone 5 screen only 4 or 5 are showing. @APesate

Comment: Thank you so much, i will do my best :D @TarvoMäesepp

Comment: @TimoCengiz you want border according to your cells.? i mean you want table height dynamic according to there cells.

Comment: If the tableview shows 4 cells then i want the border to be in the fourth cell. if it shows 5 cells it should be on the fifth cell.. @balkaransingh

Comment: @TimoCengiz check my answer

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is to take all these cells in  a same section & add *footerView* as thick `UILable` with background color of your choice.

Make Sure the `TableView` style is Grouped so it will not float.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableview.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
tableview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are several ways to accomplish this.

1. Adjust the size of the TableView so when you modify its Layer it will properly fit the whole view.

**Consideration**: Make sure the `contentSize()` of the TableView actually fits on the screen, so you don't end up with a view that's bigger than the device's screen.

2. Add only the top border and the rest of the sides to the cells, so the border will move with the cells properly and you won't end with blank spaces when the tableview scrolls.

   In other words.

   - The top border will be applied to the TableView.layer
   - The Side borders will be applied to each row. You can add them as subview or to the cell.contentView.layer. Whichever is easier for you.
   - The bottom border will be applied only to the last row.

Problem with this: if the contentSize of the tableview is bigger than the frame.size then the last cell won't appear and the border won't be visible either.

As a side note, if you want to hide the extra separators at the end of the tableview you can do this.

`tableview.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieve by getting UITableViewCell Height.

You know the cell row height, and also the number of cells.

Then just set the UITableView frame as per the calculated value.

UITableView height =  cell row height * number of cells.

Then set the border to the tableview

Comment: I know the cell height but how do i get the number or visible cells?

Comment: Ok for that you can do one thing. You just take a view and set autolayout for that view. Set border to that view. Then add a uitableview in that view.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
tableview.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
tableview.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
```

you need to take IBoutlet of hight Constraint of your Table View

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *TblHeightConstraint;
```

set table height with

```
TblHeightConstraint.constant = yourCellHight * [NumberofCells];
```

it will set your table hight daynamically.so Your border will show according to number of cell.